# Stringtokenizer to extract curly braces from the file

Tags: java

I need a stringtokenizer to read from java class file and process it and extract all the brackets like '{' '}'. Also I need to read the file and breakdown it and breakdown
its parts into tokens such as identifiers, keywords, special characters, etc.
How to accomplish this?

Assume that The input file consists of this:

```
public void run() {
    Simulation.logEvent(SimulationEvent.cookStarting(this));
    try {
        while (true) {
            //YOUR CODE GOES HERE...
            Order order = null;
            this.mainLock.lockInterruptibly();
            try {
                while (this.orderQueue.size() == 0) {
                    this.notEmptyCondition.await();
                }
                if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    order = orderQueue.poll();
                    System.out.println(this.name + " got the order: " + order);
                }
```

And I need to extract the brackets {} from this and ignoring other stuff, using stringtokenizer.

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to parse a `JSON` object, if that is the case, you should use a library like `Gson` or `json-simple`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file you are trying to parse resembles java a lot (possibly it is a java source file) this java parser might be of interest: [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/wiki/Manual)